# How to use MPI_BCast with dynamic array of own datatype objects

Tags: c++, arrays, mpi

There was a problem with passing dynamic array of object pointers via `MPI_BCast(...)`. When I try to send array that I got error `ended prematurely and may have crashed. exit code 0xc0000005`. If I use `MPI_BCast(...)` with one object (like this `MPI_Bcast(myObjArray[0], dataTypeMyObject, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`) it work correctly. What I need to change in my implementation to send the whole array?
Here is the code of my classes

```cpp
class Vector3 final
{
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
//...(methods)
}
class MyObject final
{
public:
    Vector3 Force;
    Vector3 Speed;
//...(methods)
};
```

Here is a code of datatype init

```cpp
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Datatype dataTypeVec3;
int          lenVec3[3] = { 1, 1, 1 };
MPI_Aint     posVec3[3] = { offsetof(class Vector3, x),offsetof(class Vector3, y), offsetof(class Vector3, z) };
MPI_Datatype typVec3[3] = { MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_DOUBLE };
MPI_Type_create_struct(3, lenVec3, posVec3, typVec3, &dataTypeVec3);
MPI_Type_commit(&dataTypeVec3);
MPI_Datatype dataTypeMyObject;
int          lenMyObject[2] = { 1, 1 };
MPI_Aint     posMyObject[2] = { offsetof(class MyObject, Force),offsetof(class MyObject, Speed)};
MPI_Datatype typMyObject[2] = { dataTypeVec3, dataTypeVec3};
MPI_Type_create_struct(2, lenMyObject, posMyObject, typMyObject, &dataTypeMyObject);
MPI_Type_commit(&dataTypeMyObject);
```

Here is a part of the code with `MPI_BCast(...)`

```cpp
MyObject** myObjArray = new MyObject * [10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    myobjArray[i] = new MyObject();
}
if(rank == 0)
   myObjArray[0]->Speed = {5, 0, 0};
MPI_Bcast(myObjArray, 10, dataTypeMyObject, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // Problem is here
if(rank != 0)
   std::cout << "rank = "<< rank << " and speed.x = " << myObjArray[0].Speed.x << std::endl;
```

Comment: The code where you use the `myObjArray` is incorrect. You never create a `MyObject` instance itself, i.e. `myObjArray[0]` is of type `MyObject *` which points to nothing.
Otherwise, have you checked for padding elements in the objects? I.e. is `static_assert(sizeof(Vector3)==3*sizeof(double))` and `static_assert(sizeof(MyObject)==2*sizeof(Vector3))` compiling?

Comment: This is bad C++ coding. Do not use `new`. Use a `std::vector` or `std::array`. That would prevent the sort of memory errors you are making.

Comment: @ Sedenion, I forgot to add it here. Actually I allocate it. Thnk you.

Comment: does this even compile? I do not think you can access `myObjArray[0].Speed` since you declared `MyObject ** myObjArray`

Comment: Note you do not need to `MPI_Type_commit(&dataTypeVec3)` unless you plan to use it in a communication subroutine.

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet This is work correctly. Actually I forgot to add part of  the code, but now it's fixed.

Comment: No, the code cannot compile as you have shown it. In the line `myObjArray[0].Speed = {5,0,0)};` there are two syntactic errors: `myObjArray[0]` yields a pointer, so you cannot access `Speed` via `.`. You need `->` for this. Also, there is a closing `)` without a matching opening `(`.

Comment: Also, the signature is `MPI_Bcast(void *buffer, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int root, MPI_Comm comm)`. So your line should be `MPI_Bcast(myObjArray, 10, dataTypeMyObject, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`. Notice that the 2nd and 3rd arguments are swapped. I would guess that your version should not compile.

Comment: @Sedenion, Sorry, I'm made a few mistakes here, but original code didn't have it. I have right code with correct call of field `Speed` and function 'MPI_BCast(...)'. You highlighted right things about this code, but it isn't a solution of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MPI_Bcast()` expects that the input elements are continuous in memory, i.e. that the 10 `MyObject` instances are located "behind each other" in memory. But in your case you pass in an array of pointers into `MPI_Bcast()`, but `MPI_Bcast()` will not dereference the individual pointers.
Instead, try

```
MyObject * myObjArray = new MyObject[10];
// ... initialize objects on rank 0
MPI_Bcast(myObjArray, 10, dataTypeMyObject, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```